# how to run ActiveX control in multiple browsers

Tags: c#, browser, activex

I have used an ActiveX control in my application created in visual studio. It is running perfectly in internet explorer but now, i need to run the application in different browsers such as "chrome" or "Firefox". Please let me know if any one has done this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing IETab in mozilla and chrome helps to run activex controls

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer is the only browser that supports running ActiveX controls.

You can't run these in other browsers.

Comment: as i can see some blogs where we can run activex control in mozilla. http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/159142/Running-activex-controls-in-Mozilla-Firefox

Comment: @Amish - If you follow those links, you will see they are for very old versions of Mozilla and other browsers. None of the modern ones. Consider that only Mozilla has something close to modern, so Chrome and other browsers are still out. If you want to provide cross-browser functionality, you shouldn't use proprietary functionality - use web standards (HTML5, CSS3 etc...).

Comment: Thanks Oded, But i want to have a research over it. Although i know ActiveX is only for IE but, i have to find the solution..... if possible.

Comment: @Amish - The solution? Write your own plugin for each browser, to ensure ActiveX will work. I have no idea how you would make that work on platforms other than Windows. This is not easy. A better solution is to write your application using web standards.

Comment: I have resoloved all the issues by installing IE tab.

Comment: @AmishKumar - Which means running IE _inside_ the Chrome skin. You are still running IE, not Chrome.

Comment: yeah.. but user will not aware of it and this is the only solution.. we don't have anything to say to who are nontechnical persons. they just need to run the app in any browser.